# Что такое карточки во вложениях vk_api, где они могут встречаться?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю парсер, который собирает посты при помощи vk_api. При обработке вложений обнаружил тип карточки (pretty_cards). Что это такое и где они могут встречаться?
Ссылка на документацию по  https://vk.com/dev/attachments_w  , где я эти карточки и нашёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty_cards - обычная карусель карточек, подробнее описано в документации https://dev.vk.com/method/prettyCards

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]